# Undefined function in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure why below javascript function isn't working in Firefox

```
function focus_adverts(element_one, element_two){
      element_one.on('click', function(){
        $(this).one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd animationEnd', function(){
          element_two.show().addClass('animated flipInY');
          element_two.one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd animationEnd', function(){
            element_one.hide().removeClass('flipOutY flipInY');
          });
        });
      });
    }

    focus_adverts($('#tv-advertisement'), $('#tv-advertisement-video'));
    focus_adverts($('#tv-advertisement-video'), $('#tv-advertisement'));
```

This function `focus_adverts` doesn't seem to work at all. It does not run the code inside `$(this).one` somehow...

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: What errors do you receive in the console? Can you put together a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you name CSS `animationEnd` property wrong. Try this

```
$(this).one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() { ...
```

Note: `animationend` and `oanimationend` are all lowercase. Seems to me that latest Firefox does not use `mozAnimationEnd` anymore and expect W3C `animationend`, which you never provided.

#### Proof demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FNUy6/

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your calls are made after the DOM has finished loading:

```
$(function(){
    focus_adverts($('#tv-advertisement'), $('#tv-advertisement-video'));
    focus_adverts($('#tv-advertisement-video'), $('#tv-advertisement'));
});
```

Comment: It's already wrapped under `$(function(){});`